# How to remove inline css with jQuery onClick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with inline style:

```
<div class="voucher-text" style="display: block;">
```

I need to remove the display: block; style with onClick action on the body(Not on the .voucher-text  div);

Comment: jQuery [.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the whole style attribute:

```
$('div.voucher-text').removeAttr("style");
```

or just the `display` style:

```
$('div.voucher-text').css({display:""});
```

To fire it from a click handler on the document:

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    $('div.voucher-text').css({display:""});
});
```

If you specifically need it on the `<body>` element, and not the document (not sure why that'd make a difference):

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
    $('div.voucher-text').css({display:""});
});
```

Comment: With onClick action on the body(Not on the .voucher-text div);

Comment: Edited my answer to include `<body>` specifically.